# What is the behaviour of imap_sort when $search_criteria are null?

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

The documentation of [`imap_sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-sort.php) can take `$search_criteria` as an argument, but by default, `$search_criteria` is set to `NULL`.

```
imap_sort ( resource $imap_stream , int $criteria , int $reverse [, int $options = 0 [, string $search_criteria = NULL [, string $charset = NULL ]]] ) : array
```

My question is: 
**what is the behaviour of imap_sort when $search_criteria is null?**

- The documentation refers to [`imap_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) but that doesn't help at all, because there isn't a null argument there.

I need to know this because my version of phpimap (https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) doesn't take a search criteria argument and I need ALL mails, thus this would normally be 'ALL' as a search criterium.

So is NULL equal to 'ALL'?

Comment: Have you tried using it? If you need **all** mails, why not omit any search parameter?

Comment: Because that is not documented. I need to be certain.